# Which is the better way to implement initialization in an Angular application?

Tags: angular

I'm implementing a front-end which communicates in several ways with the back-end (HTTP APIs, websocket).

Before anything is rendered I need some data structures to be initialized and some operations to be performed. Obviously it is all asynchronous operations and I need to be sure they are finished before going on. Furthermore some of these operations use the output of another operation, which then needs to be launched before. In other words the order and sequentiality of the operations must be guaranteed.

First I put these operations into the `ngOnInit` of the `app.component.ts`, but it didn't work.

Then I found out the use of `providers` along with the `APP_INITIALIZER` token in the `app.module.ts` and it worked perfectly for independent operations (operations that don't need any input parameter) and it guarantees the execution order (not sure about sequentiality).

```
...
providers: [
    { 
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initOne,
      deps: [OneService],
      multi: true
    },
    { 
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initTwo,
      deps: [TwoService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
...
```

Then it came up the need of having parameters coming as the result of former operations. Also I would like to have some scalability, so the `providers` array could grow in the future.

I was wondering if this is still the right way to implement the init operations?

Maybe a dedicated initialization service could fit better with my requirements and with best practices?

Something like this:

`initialization.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InitializationService {

  constructor(
    private serviceOne: OneService,
    private serviceTwo: TwoService,
    private serviceThree: ThreeService,
    ...
  ) { }
  
  public init() {
    serviceOne.init().subscribe((output1) => {
       serviceTwo.init().subscribe((output2) => {
          serviceThree.init().subscribe((output3) => {
             ...
          });
       });
    });
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import {InitializationService} from './core/services/initialization.service'
...
export function initialization(initializationService: InitializationService) {
   return () => initializationService.init();
}
...
providers: [
   { 
     provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
     useFactory: initialization,
     deps: [InitializationService],
     multi: true
   },
]
```

Comment: aubscribe in subscribe is always a bad pratice. change it to a pipe operator chanin with switchMap

Comment: use `CombineLatest()` or `forkJoin` if your services can be called in parallel.

Comment: here the point is not how to concatenate a sequence of asynch calls, rather on what is the best practice to have these calls in the app initialization, and have them all finished before anything is rendered